# My code works but eventually enters infinite loop when i interrupt i get "raw_input was called, but this frontend does not support input requests."

Tags: python

Code link [here](https://github.com/Doug160516/Poker-Game/tree/main)

I can run it fine but after enough inputs it will reach the above error and I don't understand why

```
KeyboardInterrupt                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-032e7a07544e> in <module>
----> 1 game(a,b)

<ipython-input-25-0243021db553> in game(player_1, player_2)
    834         keep_playing_choice=""
    835         while keep_playing_choice not in ['Y','y','N','n','Yes','yes','No','no']:
--> 836                 keep_playing_choice=input('Would you like to play again? ')
    837                 if keep_playing_choice in ['Y','y','Yes','yes']:
    838                     clear_output()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py in raw_input(self, prompt)
    858                 "raw_input was called, but this frontend does not support input requests."
    859             )
--> 860         return self._input_request(str(prompt),
    861             self._parent_ident,
    862             self._parent_header,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py in _input_request(self, prompt, ident, parent, password)
    902             except KeyboardInterrupt:
    903                 # re-raise KeyboardInterrupt, to truncate traceback
--> 904                 raise KeyboardInterrupt("Interrupted by user") from None
    905             except Exception as e:
    906                 self.log.warning("Invalid Message:", exc_info=True)
```